# XML Deserialization with Polymorphism and Exception Handling

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I am creating a service using Microsoft ASP.NET Web API with the following requirements:

1. Input must be in XML (no json)
2. XML will follow a standard (cannot add custom element names/attributes to the input xml)
3. When encountering exceptions in deserialization (i.e. data values in bad format) they must be logged as warnings and parsing of the input xml must continue
4. The XML will contain collections of elements in which the elements need to be
   deserialized into types derived from a base type

Requirements 1 and 2 simply define my input. I started developing my solution by using the built-in `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer` class, but had to abandon it because it could not handle requirement #3.

Alternately, I found [YAXLib](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34045/Yet-Another-XML-Serialization-Library-for-the-NET) which provided a very [useful way](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34045/Yet-Another-XML-Serialization-Library-for-the-NET#deser) to handle requirement #3.

YAXLib also handles requirement #4, but only by utilizing custom attributes in the XML:

```
  <ListOfObjects>
    <Object yaxlib:realtype="System.Int32">7</Object>
    <Object yaxlib:realtype="System.Double">3.14</Object>
    <Object yaxlib:realtype="System.String">Congrats</Object>
    <Object yaxlib:realtype="System.StringSplitOptions">RemoveEmptyEntries</Object>
  </ListOfObjects>
```

Because of requirement #2, I cannot use this approach. I need something like the `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute` so I can instruct the serializer in code, not in the data. **Is there an existing solution out there that will handle all of these requirements?**

### Example:

**Input**

```
<DEALS>
    <DEAL>
        <COLLATERALS>
            <COLLATERAL>xyz</COLLATERAL>
            <COLLATERAL>1.2</COLLATERAL>
            <COLLATERAL>4.5</COLLATERAL>
        </COLLATERALS>
        <LOANS>
            <LOAN>
                <CLOSING_INFORMATION />
            </LOAN>
        </LOANS>
    </DEAL>
</DEALS>
```

**C# Classes**

```
public class DEAL
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("COLLATERALS", typeof(COLLATERALS))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("LOANS", typeof(LOANS))]
    [YAXCollection(YAXCollectionSerializationTypes.RecursiveWithNoContainingElement)]
    public object[] Items
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }

    // Remaining implementation details omitted..
}

public class COLLATERALS { /* details omitted.. */ }
public class LOANS { /* details omitted.. */ }

public class COLLATERAL
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

**Expected Output**

Objects in the Items collection of the `DEALS` class should be deserialized into their respective types: `COLLATERALS` and `LOANS`. Also, the first collateral with the value 'xyz' will not get deserialized (since the type is `decimal`) but the remaining valid `COLLATERAL` items would get deserialized. The error parsing 'xyz' to decimal should be logged somehow.

Comment: I strongly suggest writing up an XML schema that defines valid/invalid input.  (XML already has a defined syntax for defining a schema.)  It will simplify testing if input is valid for both you, and potential users of your service without needing to actually hit the service itself.

Comment: @Servy This was the original idea. I do have an XSD that defines the valid schema. However, we have some users that will be sending us data from their existing software, and cannot guarantee they will be able to do validation against the XSD on their end prior to sending the data, so we moved the validation to the time of parsing.

Comment: Clearly you need an overly forgiving parser, so you can't just plug in the XSD and be done, but it's still worth defining as it will help your development efforts, testing efforts, and help developers writing code that uses this service (assuming you publish the XSD).  Since it doesn't actually solve the problem I posted a comment not an answer.

Comment: @Servy Thanks for the input. I think that, since my question was about a solution to handle these 4 requirements, your solution of client-side validation of XML against XSD in conjunction with using `XmlSerializer` on the server for polymorphic deserialization would be the best option. You could post that in the form of an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an XML Schema (an XSD file) to define what the valid format of an XML file is.  There are existing tools which will validate whether or not a particular file complies with a schema or not.

By providing this schema publicly you will be able to allow your clients to validate their own requests without needing to actually interact with your web service.  It will allow them to see if their inputs are valid, and if they need to perform complex analysis on what specifically needs to be changed to comply they would be capable of doing that on their own.